# possible to set all items of a has_many relationship to a certain value without looping through them in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have in Rails 3.1:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I'd like to do something

```
cat=Category.find(1)
cat.items.is_enabled=true
cat.save
```

but can't and need to set each via a loop. Is there some way to just set these all at once?

thx

Comment: the `is_enabled` attribute of Catagory or Item?

Comment: is_enabled is attribute on item

Comment: well, i think loop will make your life easier, just `cat.items.each do |item| item.is_enabled = true item.save end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 cat.items.update_all(:is_enabled => true)
```